# Constraint Layout makes application too slow

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, kotlin

I have developed an application using Constraint layout for all the layout, I have experienced that navigating between activities and when comes back to previous screen app takes some times than actual, I suspect that that constraint layout cause slow rendering, Is constraint layout really makes application to slow rendering?

Comment: It's not the `ConstraintLayout`. It's probably what you have in the layout.

Comment: i faced the same problem and i was struggling with it for two days , when i replaced the constrianlayout with normal linear or relative layout container it becomes much more faster, that's a very weird problem

Comment: ConstraintLayout v 2.0 is the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with ConstraintLayout 2.0.1. I updated it to the newest version and now my application runs and renders really faster and the frames skip problem is resolved!